# What is the relation between linear and angular velocity? How is v = rω derived?

Tags: velocity, angular-velocity

What is the relation between linear and angular velocity? How is $v = r\omega$ derived?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no evidence of prior effort.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55077/discussion-on-question-by-roshan-tabriaz-what-is-the-relation-between-linear-and).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @GRrocks for guiding me through. This is how $v = r\omega$ is derived:

1. $velocity = {displacement\over time}$
2. $v = {ds\over dt}$
3. Since our displacement/distance is the length of the arc which is made by the angle $d\theta$: $s = rd\theta$
4. $v = {rd\theta\over dt}$
5. Since $r$ is constant: $v = r{d\theta\over dt}$
6. ${d\theta\over dt} = \omega$
7. Therefore! $v = r\omega$

Comment: Prefer infinitesimally small terms - namely dr, d(theta), dt.

Comment: @AaronJohnSabu Thanks, I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

Hint- $v={ds}/{dt}$. What does this $s$ represent(i.e. which 'path' is your object on)? We know angular velocity is the rate of change of angular displacement, i.e. $\omega=d\theta/dt$.What is the relation between $s$ and $\theta$? Are they proportional? Plug in the known data in the first equation.

I believe this should be sufficient.

Comment: Yes it suffices the need

Answer (score 0):

It's simple since velocity = $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and displacement is the arc length so $x = r\theta$ and only theta varies not the radius so $\frac{dx}{dt}=r\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ which is $v= r\omega $.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Please use mathjax to format mathematical expressions. To learn more about mathjax, please read [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Hint

$l=r\theta$

Differentiating with respect to time.

$\dfrac{dl}{dt}=r\dfrac{d\theta}{dt}$

**V**=r$\omega $

Comment: Ask me in comments if you don't understand anything