# Velocity of a point on the surface of a sphere rolling with slipping

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, velocity, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

[image]

Here a sphere is rolling on a frictional surface but slipping takes place. Hence, the velocity of the bottom-most point is not equal to $0$. Hence, $v_{cm} \ne R\omega$. The angular velocity of the sphere is $\omega$.

Let's say I want to find the tangential velocity ($v_t$) and thereafter the total velocity of another point on the surface of the sphere. Is this relation correct? $$v_t = R\omega + v_{cm} \cos(\theta)$$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $v_t$ and $v_{cm}$.

If this is correct, does it mean that even though there is slipping, we can use $v = R\omega$ for finding the linear velocity due to the angular velocity of any other point except the bottom-most one.

Comment: Not only for sphere but $$v= \omega \cross R$$ always hold, like even if you moving on road, you are moving in a circle with respect to a fixed point and radius vector is adjusted according to that.(provided that point to reference not on the road on which you are moving.)

Comment: $$v=wr$$ when radius vector and velocity vector are perpendicular, $v$ can be less than $wr$ or greater than.

Comment: The resultant velocity for any point in a wheel is the VECTOR SUM of the tangential velocity (relative to the center of mass) and the velocity of the center of mass. In a slipping wheel, both of these may be changing with time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1**.  The condition for rolling without slipping is $V_{cm}$=.

**2**. Irrespective of whether a body is slipping or not, velocity due to rotation of any point can be related as $V$=, where R is the radius of curvature and  is the angular velocity. So yes, the relation holds good and the magnitude of tangential velocity can be found using the formula mentioned in your question.

**3**. The total velocity of a point can be obtained by taking vector sum of $V_{cm}$ and $V$. The magnitude can be found out as
$$V_{total}=\sqrt{V_{cm}^{2}+V^{2}+2V_{cm}.V.cos(\theta )} $$

Comment: I think tangential velocity will also include a component of velocity of center of mass as I have shown in the question...

Comment: Please also confirm if the assumption I have made in the last paragraph is correct or not and provide a reason for it...

Comment: Yes, there will be a component of velocity of centre of mass.

Comment: And the expression used by you is indeed correct

Comment: Could you provide a reason for why $v = R \omega$ holds true even though there is slipping...

Comment: @HSB You can find the reason here - https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/317480/what-is-the-relation-between-linear-and-angular-velocity-how-is-v-rω-derived